# resistor values in non-inverting op amp with bias

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
\newcommand{\rth}{R_{TH}}
\newcommand{\vth}{V_{TH}}
\newcommand{\rf}{R_{F}}
$$

I'm stumped (hence posting here!) with what is probably a very simple extrapolation.

Consider this circuit:

[image: Non-inverting op amp with 3.3V bias]

The values supplied are based on an example that I am working with.  I need to better understand how the resistance values were derived as I need to change the reference (from 3.3V to 2.5V), the $V_{in}$ (from 0 to 3.3V to 0 to 2.5V), and the $V_{out}$ from $\pm 36V$ to $\pm 40V$.

So I'm seeking guidance on how to calculate the resistor values.  Leading up to this, I have a good understanding.

Here is the transfer function for this circuit:
$$
   OUT = IN (1 + \frac{\rf}{\rth}) - \vth \frac{\rf}{\rth}.
$$
The opamp is supplied with +45 and -45 V rails and it can safely swing between $\pm 40V$ at those levels.

The desired output will go from $-40$ to $-40V$ as the input goes from $0$ to $+2.5V$ (at $1.25V$ the output will sit at $0V$).

The gain is calculated thusly:

\begin{align}
  Gain (\text{non-inverting}) &= (36 - (-36))/3.3 = 72/3.3 = 21.81818182\\
  Gain(\text{inverting}) &= Gain (\text{non-inverting}) - 1 = 20.81818182 = \frac{\rf}{\rth}
\end{align}

The resistor values are calculated using this formula:
$$
    \vth = 3.3 V (\frac{R_2 }{ R_1 + R_2}).
$$

First, I must find $\vth$.  Here's the formula for that:

\begin{align}
    -36 V &= 0 - \vth (\frac{\rf}{\rth})\\    
    \vth &= 1.729257642 V
\end{align}

In the above, $\frac{\rf}{\rth}$ is taken as an unknown, so:
\begin{align}
    -36V &= 0-\vth \frac{\rf}{\rth}\\
    -36/20.81818182 = \vth
\end{align}

Now, here's the sticky part:
\begin{align}
  \vth &= 3.3 V \frac{R_2 }{ (R_1 + R_2)}\\
  1.729257642 V &= 3.3 V \frac{R_2}{(R_1 + R_2)}\\
  1.729257642/3.3 V &= \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2}\\
  1.729257642/3.3 V &= 0.5240\\
\end{align}

From $0.5240$, how in blazes do I calculate the value of $R_2$, $R_1$ and $\rf$?
$$
\rf = gain * \rth
$$
( but $\rth$ is $R_2/(R_1+R_2)$ ):

$$
  \rf  = 20.81818182 * \rth
$$
Seems as if I need to choose one value out of the blue to get the others??

Comment: I could probably answer your question, but I'd like to point out that you're going to have a really tough time sourcing a $108.909 k\Omega$ resistor, and that circuits that depend on this kind of tolerance are generally a really bad idea, at least according to the folks who wrote "The Art of Electronics," who seem to know a thing or two.

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to fix the formatting; please be sure I haven't broken anything as I did so.

Comment: Consider asking your question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @JohnHughes These are the mathematical results of the values which were provided in my sample circuit with 3.3V and +-36V rails.  From derived values I can simulate and tweak for 1% values...

Comment: @JohnHughes Re-formatting looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You'll notice, if you look at your equations, that if you double (or triple, or multiply by $63.2$) each of $R_1, R_2, R_{TH},$ and $R_F$, the gain and all the voltages remain the same. Thus there is no single solution to this problem.

So your conclusion is correct: you *do* have to pick one of them, and then all the others follow from that.

Typically (as far as I know about circuits), you pick the values so that the currents involved are not too large (which depends on your op-amp, etc., I'm guessing), but so that they are large enough that any stray voltages (capacitance-coupled wiring, etc.) are insignificant. Picking those wisely is the part of the dark art that kept me from ever trying to design anything like this for a serious purpose. :)